# 1's complement - Can 1 bit or 2 bit errors go undetected? How? Why?

Tags: networking, tcp, header, udp, packet

Within a network packet header, when 1's complement is used with 8 bit bytes (rather than the 16 bits normally used in TCP), can a 1 bit error go undetected?

can a 2 bit error go undetected?

If they can how and why does this happen?

Comment: The TCP checksum uses 16-bit words, not 8-bit bytes, so this question is moot.

Comment: The word you're looking for is 'complement '.

Comment: I got this question in a third year Comp Science Class assignment. While I have found some Yes or No answers around the internet, I have not found anyone that can explain why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the way a 1's complement works with 3 8-bit bytes. (rather than the 16 bits in TCP)

```
   10011001
+  01010010
___________
   11101011
+  01011001
___________
1  01000100
          1   Wrap Around and add 9th Bit
___________
   01000101  <- Sum
___________
   10111010  <- 1’s Complement
```

If there are 1 Bit errors they will all be detected, however 2-bit errors can go undetected.

```
   10011000 <- last bit switched (should be 10011001) 
+  01010011 <- last bit switched (should be 01010010)
___________
   11101011
+  01011001
___________
1  01000100
          1 <- Wrap Around and add 9th Bit
___________
   01000101 <- Sum
___________
   10111010 <- 1’s Complement with 2 bit error is the same as previous answer
```